# How can i make chat boxes beside each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a question about chat boxes

i have this script

```js
$(function(){

$(".sidebar-name").click(function(){
var userid = $(this).attr('id');
$(".chatbox[id="+userid+"]").show();
$(".chattexts").animate({ scrollTop: 200 }, 50);
return false;
});

$(".closechat").click(function(){
var userid = $(this).attr('id');
$(".chatbox[id="+userid+"]").hide();
return false;
});

});
```

```css
*{padding: 0; margin: 0; outline: 0;}
body {
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 14px;
}

/*chat menu*/
.chat-sidebar {
 width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
}
.sidebar-name {
 padding: 10px;
 border-top: solid 1px #222;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #444;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.sidebar-name:first-child {
 border-top: 0px;
}
.sidebar-name:last-child {
 border-bottom: 0px;
}
/*chat menu*/


/*chat box*/
.chatbox {
 border: solid 1px #333;
 width: 250px;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 9;
 position: fixed;
 right: 210px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 display: none;
}
.hedchatbox {
 background: #555;
 color: #fff;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
 padding: 5px;
}
.hedchatbox .closechat {
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.chattexts {
 height: 200px;
 border: solid 1px #444;
 margin: 5px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
.chattexts .prfromme {
 background: #ccc;
 padding: 2px;
 text-align: center;
}
.chattexts .forpr {
 background: #f0f0f0;
 padding: 2px;
 text-align: center;
}
.textareachat {
 padding: 5px;
 padding-top: 0px;
}
.textareachat .texttypechat {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 resize: none;
 width: 190px;
 padding: 3px;
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 12px;
}
/*end chat box*/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>title</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="chat-sidebar">
<div id="1" class="sidebar-name">mahmoud samy</div>
<div id="2" class="sidebar-name">samy ahmed</div>
<div id="3" class="sidebar-name">mohamed ahmed</div>
<div id="4" class="sidebar-name">medo medo</div>
</div>



<div class="chatbox" id="1">
<div class="hedchatbox"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> mahmoud samy 
 <div class="closechat" id="1">close</div>
</div>
<div class="chattexts">
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
</div>
<div class="textareachat"><textarea class="texttypechat" placeholder="type your message"></textarea></div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox" id="2">
<div class="hedchatbox"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> samy ahmed
 <div class="closechat" id="2">close</div>
</div>
<div class="chattexts">
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
</div>
<div class="textareachat"><textarea class="texttypechat" placeholder="type your message"></textarea></div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox" id="3">
<div class="hedchatbox"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> mohamed ahmed
 <div class="closechat" id="3">close</div>
</div>
<div class="chattexts">
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
</div>
<div class="textareachat"><textarea class="texttypechat" placeholder="type your message"></textarea></div>
</div>

<div class="chatbox" id="4">
<div class="hedchatbox"> medo medo
 <div class="closechat" id="4">close</div>
</div>
<div class="chattexts">
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
<p class="prfromme">hi, how are you?</p>
<p class="forpr">i'm fine</p>
<p class="forpr">what about you?</p>
<p class="prfromme">i'm good</p>
</div>
<div class="textareachat"><textarea class="texttypechat" placeholder="type your message"></textarea></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and when i click on any user his chat box is shown but if i click to another user it show also but on old chat box 
i want to make the chat boxes beside each other any body can help me?

and thanks all

Comment: have you tried `float`